# How can I capture and analyse LTE packets using Wireshark and LTE modem?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, network-protocols

Is it possible to analyse LTE packets using Wireshark. I'm having trouble using Wireshark to capture mobile LTE traffic. I ma using a MacBook and a LTE modem.

Do I need specific configuration to capture LTE traffic on Wireshark. 
Or is it possible this, any idea.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the Wireshark documentation on LTE or done research on how to view/capture this traffic yet? What have you tried?